# Increase max file count in ntfs drive

Tags: manjaro, ulimit

As of late. I started getting an error of no space in drive when installing node apps although I have lots of free space. After some digging I found out that the problem is when having to many files.
I've tried increasing max watcher limit, max file limit, soft and hard limits and nothing seems to work. I've been forced to delete the projects I'm not working on at the moment in order to make space for installing new projects or even saving my files. This really unsustainable.

I'm using manjaro Linux. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You note your are using manjero linux, why are you using an NTFS drive then? EXT4 for example, has huge limits on files. Can you provide insight into: Why ntfs and not EXT4 or XFS or something else? What number of files are we talking about? Are you sure you hitting the limit?

Comment: I also have windows installed, that's why I'm using NTFS for my data partition. I have about 4 million files in that partition. Currently and working with a lot of node projects and they add so many files, specially angular apps. I started having the error when installing a node app and at first thought it was a node related issue. Then it also happened when unzipping a project. I've toped all things related to inodes and max_files watcher. Even though the inode count for the drive has never been above 20%. I really have no idea what else to do.